# Using wine for window printer driver on Linux

Tags: linux, unix, printing, printer, wine

We have some old printers with Windows drivers only at my work space. Is there any general way to use their drivers through wine?

I have not found any decent and new documentation about the problem.

**Edit**

We have Sharp AR-5516, and according to http://www.openprinting.org/printers there are not any Linux drivers.

There is very ancient documentation which states it is possible: 
http://www.witch.westfalen.de/Wine-HOWTO/wineprintconfig.html
see the *Printing Using a Windows Driver* section

We use Gentoo Linux with a custom kernel (3.18.12) configuration, with cups-2.0.3 . Printers with native Linux support work as excepted.

Comment: I don't think wine deals with hardware/driver.

Comment: Freshplayer uses Wine to run Windows Flash, but I don't know if it uses the Windows video drivers or translates back to the Linux driver.  However, that said, the universal drivers for Linux are pretty comprehensive...

Comment: Wine is not for hardware drivers, that will not work. Some Windows only printers will just not work in Linux, sorry, but what is your printer because their may be another way? Please provide more details of the actual problem, make, model, distro, etc...

Comment: @acejavelin I updated the question.

Comment: It is funny, I tried to help someone get virtually this identical model printer working a few weeks ago in Linux, the result was a replacement printer. I kind of LOL when I read the documentation you had linked on Printing in Wine and said it was ancient, note at the bottom "Windows directory of my Windows for Workgroups installation" this implies Windows 3.11, meaning early 1990's. To my knowledge, you can't do that anymore with more modern Windows.